# If $X\in\{0,1\}$, then $\frac{cov(X,Y)}{Var(X)}=\mathbb{E}(Y|X=1)-\mathbb{E}(Y|X=0)$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, variance, covariance, conditional-expectation

If $X\in\{0,1\}$, then $\frac{cov(X,Y)}{Var(X)}=\mathbb{E}(Y|X=1)-\mathbb{E}(Y|X=0)$

I have no idea what to address with the conditional expectation part.

Thank you for any comments, someone has provides a solution that I cannot understand. Please help me out with this question sincerely.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4463922/if-x-in-0-1-then-fraccovx-yvarx-mathbbeyx-1-mathbbeyx

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $E[X] = P(X=1)$, and
$E[XY] = E[Y\cdot 1|X=1]P(X=1) + E[Y\cdot0]P(X=0) = E[Y|X=1]E[X]$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is that using iterated expectation? but I am still not be able to proceed forward  :(

Comment: You have the full answer. Explain which part you dont understand

Comment: I cannot see how does it relevant to the question.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help if you don't explain what you don't understand

Comment: would you please write out to reach the equation as in the question

Comment: It is already written in the answer you linked in your question